# Is there a way to empty the browser appcache on mobile browsers?

Tags: mobile, web, chrome

On any mobile browser. Any info would be appreciated. I think I know how to do it on mobile safari, but I don't know about any of the others.

Comment: Please ask this question on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use those links :

Mozilla https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clearing-cookies-private-data-history-and-settings

Chrome https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392709?hl=en